# In mysql, in or like query is it possible to get the maximum matched result at the top?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from abc where xyz like $x or xyz like $y or xyz like $ z
```

So, in this `query` is it automatic that the result with the maximum number of `like` would be listed at the top?

If not what needs to be added to get that done?

Comment: `LIKE` and `IN` operators work differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean TRUE and FALSE expressions can be treated as integer 1 and 0. Therefore, you can simply sum the values, and order by that value:

```
SELECT * FROM abc
WHERE xyz LIKE $x OR xyz LIKE $y OR xyz LIKE $z
ORDER BY ((xyz LIKE $x) + (xyz LIKE $y) + (xyz LIKE $z)) DESC
```

Comment: This query is right for @Shiwang. However 'like' is replaceable by '='  if there are no regular expressions used

Comment: c'mon, just a copy of mine ;)

Comment: It is not exactly correct to say `Boolean TRUE and FALSE expressions can be treated as integer 1 and 0.`. What is correct is `Boolean TRUE and FALSE values can be treated as integer 1 and 0.`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html#id657708

Comment: Thanks I guess helps me out and the usage of like is because I want to check for tags so users might just write them anywhere in the string

Comment: @Skrol29, those are Boolean expressions, not values.

Answer (score 2):

it's a complex useage-scenario...

you want to FILTER resources AND rank them in one step.... try this following dirty hackaround ;)

```
select * from abc where xyz like $x or xyz like $y or xyz like $ z ORDER BY ( xyz like $x + xyz like $y + xyz like $z) DESC
```

Comment: Your first version was not correct: `(xyz like $x) OR (xyz like $y) OR (xyz like $z)` will always return 0 or 1 whatever the number of matching LIKE. This is because operator `OR` returns a boolean, not a number.

Comment: ???
they are implicitly converted to integers

0+0+0 => 0; 1+1+1 => 3... the range from 0 to 3 will be possible

Comment: yes, but your first version was `(xyz like $x) OR (xyz like $y) OR (xyz like $z)`, isn't it ? `(true OR true OR true) = true = 1`.

Comment: no?!?!?!
"ORDER BY ( xyz like $x + xyz like $y + xyz like $z) DESC"
this was the *only* version i commited to this question.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by `maximum matched result at the top`? by the way, you can further rewrite the query as,

```
select * 
from abc 
where xyz IN ($x, $y, $z)
```

on more thing, `LIKE` is used for pattern-matching. while `IN` is used to find value within set.

Comment: not correct: $x $y and $z look like injected PHP variables. It may contains wildcards.

Comment: yes, those are php variables. i assumed that the statement was created inside php code.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `LIKE` unless you need to do a string comparison with a wildcard operator such as `%` or `_`. If you are trying to compare `xyz` to *exact* $x, $y, or $z, then use the `IN` operator like so:

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE xyz IN ($x, $y, $z)
```